# Modify RecyclerView adapter to show different layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to create a survey and display the questions in a recyclerView, but all the question types have different layouts, how can I display the correct layout depending on the question type?

The questions have a method called `getResponse_type_id` which returns a number between 1-4 which is the type of question. How should I modify the adapter to make this possible.

My adapter right now is super basic, this is what I have

```
public class SurveyQuestionsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SurveyQuestionsAdapter.QuestionViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<SurveyQuestions> mQuestionList;

    public static class QuestionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView questionTitle;
        public TextView questionOptional;
        public TextView questionInstructions;

        public QuestionViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //these are shared fields in all the question type layouts
            questionTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_name);
            questionOptional = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_optional);
            questionInstructions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_instructions);


        }
    }

    public SurveyQuestionsAdapter(ArrayList<SurveyQuestions> questions) {
        mQuestionList = questions;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QuestionViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //this is where the layout gets passed but how can I do it depending on the question type here
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout., parent, false);
        QuestionViewHolder qvh = new QuestionViewHolder(view);

        return qvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SurveyQuestions current = mQuestionList.get(position);

        //I can get the question type here like this current.getResponse_type_id()
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mQuestionList.size();
    }
}
```

The questions have this info, when sending to the adapter it is a List of questions, below is a single question.

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "question": "asdf",
      "instruction": "asdf",
      "response_type_id": 1,
      "optional": 0,
      "num": null,
      "rank": null,
      "show_text": null,
      "pivot": {
        "survey_id": 1,
        "survey_question_id": 1,
        "order": 0
      },
      "survey_question_option": []
    },
```

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example your answer is here

Answer (score 0):

You should use the power of **ViewHolderTypes**. You should create **4** Viewholders, each Viewholder represents question type.

check [this article](https://medium.com/@gilbertchristopher/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-22619a5ad365) which clarified how to use different viewTypes in recyclerView.

Comment: is this better that just using different layouts ?

Comment: It preferable to make separate Viewholders as it.make your code more readable maintainable. Your Viewholders maybe should bind in many ways so you should make dofferent Viewholders.

Answer (score 0):

We're doing something similar...

It works well for us. We created a "widget" class for each type of thing to display - these would be your question types (I recommend creating a base class Question) - they're strictly data, no Android refs at all. You'll create a list of these to represent the form on the screen, and pass that list to the recyclerview adapter (I describe it below).

Assign each type of question a unique integer; this will be the item view type used in the adapter.

Next, create a subclass of RecyclerView.ViewHolder that has a bind function that will take your question type. Something like

abstact class QuestionViewHolder<QUESTION_TYPE:Question>: ViewHolder { abstract fun bind(question: QUESTION_TYPE) }

Then create a QuestionViewHolder subclass for each type of data (passing it in as the type qualifier), with a corresponding layout for each. The view holder should have a bind function that will be passed the question object and set up the data in the layout. The view holder can then update the data in the question object as the user makes changes.

Create an Adapter for the recycler view. The key here is to implement getItemViewType(int) - you'll look up which question is at that position, and return an integer that represents the question type. You'll need to specify the view holder type, probably QuestionViewHolder (you'll probably have to play with the generic types once you get going... If the generics cause issues, and they might b/c it's an "in" variance, drop the generic type on the QuestionViewHolder, passing in Question as the parameter to the bind function, and cast it to the type you need for each subclass... I had to play with ours quite a bit to get the generics just right across all the classes - may not be worth the effort, and you can just cast in the bind function...)

In the adapter's onCreateViewHolder, create the ViewHolder instance that matches the itemViewType passed in.

In the adapter's onBindViewHolder, just look up the question to display and pass it to the bind function you created in the view holder.

And that's the gist of it...

The other option would be to just create views and add them to a long LinearLayout, but if the form is long, performance can be bad - the recycler view is nice b/c it can reuse the same question chunks.